# Sword with a perpendicular grip

Tags: weapons

I've been thinking about a sword or other bladed weapon having a perpendicular grip/handle similar to a modern policeman's baton- would there be any obvious benefits or flaws in such a design?

Comment: Have you done any research on this?  Maybe pick up a typical hand saw (where the handle is perpendicular to the blade) and see how it feels when waving it around.  Pick a safe location with no easily breakable things or people before doing so, obviously.

Comment: -1 for not doing any research. Had you researched the pros and cons of a bladed [tonfa](https://thekarateblog.com/tonfa-weapon/) you would have discovered [this question has already been answered](https://youtu.be/3bU7QPYDSfw). Please remember we are not a free research service. You are expected to do your due diligence.

Comment: Yup, downvote for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

#### Paulus Hector Mair Tells All!

Fortunately for you, there really is nothing new under the Sun! Not often thought of as a 'proper' weapon, the basic agricultural scythe is essentially a cutting sword with a perpendicular handle and one can fight using this as a weapon. (Do note that scythes have evolved over the years, and that the techniques described may not be suitable in your locale and century!)

The above named fellow wrote a fighting technique book a few centuries ago and is one of the very few known to have addressed the scythe as a weapon.

[image: https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Paulus_Hector_Mair/Image_comparison]

1. Two High Cuts with the Scythe

Present yourself like so in this piece: When you both are going together, stand with your left foot ahead and hold your scythe on your right side with your left hand at the lower grip, your right on the middle one. At that moment cut to his left side, in around toward his right arm. If he cuts at you like that and you also are standing with your left foot toward him, and you too are holding your scythe on your right side with your left hand at the lower grip, your right at the middle one, then leap in a triangle and set his cut off outside in front with your scythe on your right side. Now step in there out of triangle with your left leg and cut at his neck. If he cuts high at you in that way, then step backwards with your left leg and parry his cut outside in front on your scythe. In the same moment, nimbly step in there again and wind your scythe behind your head and out from there with a cut from your left side to the right side of his head, and with that, step back away from him.

Answer (score 1):

**Forearm crutch style.**

[image: forearm crutch]
[source](https://enablingtech.com/products/superlite-crutches-forearm-adjustable-economy)

I think the trouble with the right angle grip is that the blade will swivel if the grip rotates in your hand.  That might be desirable for a baton if you want the baton against your forearm - less desirable for a sword blade.

Forearm crutches prevent swivelling of the long end with the brace around the forearm.  The combo of a right angle grip and forearm brace seems to me a good one for a sword - you could augment power with the whole arm beyond what just your wrist could support and the grip angle is more natural.

Prior musings on the subject -
https://www.halfbakery.com/idea/Forearm_20Crutch_20Mace
where the forearm crutches are exactly that, but made out of sledgehammers.